# How to put the windows close button on the right?

Tags: window-buttons

I'm used to the close button in the upper right corner as in MS Windows. How to put it there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just paste the following in your terminal,

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/metacity/general/button_layout" --type string ":minimize,maximize,close"
```

Now you can see that your buttons are placed in the right side.

To revert:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/metacity/general/button_layout" --type string "minimize,maximize,close:"
```

Comment: I corrected the quotes but you need to approve it

Comment: Is it working with Unity when app window is maximized and window buttons integrate to top panel? (I'm not using 11.04 as waiting for its final release, but curious to know if it works.)

Comment: COOL! Can you tell how to revert the changes? :D

Answer (score 2):

If you are less comfortable with then command line, then this is also a feature present in [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/). This application helps you "tweak" many things on your Ubuntu installation, and I find it very useful (and very well maintained!).

Answer (score 1):

Or you just install *gconf-editor* on your Ubuntu, then open it and look for *apps* >> *metacity* >> *general* >> *button_layout*

change the value to:

> :minimize,maximize,close

Which means "fill with blank space, minimize, maximize, close", making the buttons to be shown at right.

Comment: For Version 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) this is a necessary step since gconf-editor is not installed by default.  Accessing this utility directly also provides an answer to the question of rollback.  I believe that the original setting is "close,maximize,minimize:"